# PyQt. Create button which will be in pressed state when it's clicked

Tags: qt, pyqt

everyone. I started learning pyQt and I want a button which will be when clicked always in pressed state and when it's going to be clicked again , it's going to be released. I guess it can be achieved with QtWidgets.QPushButton, but which flags to use I don't know. I tried to read all of them , but a lot still looks so hard to grasp. Can anybody help newbie ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [QPushButton](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#checkable-prop) and you have to enable `QPushButton::setCheckable` to true. Note: this flag is not available in Qt Creator and must be set programatically.

> setCheckable() sets whether the button is a toggle button or not.